# How do I mutate a variable from inside a rust closure

Tags: rust, closures

I'm trying to implement an `EventListener` like interface in rust. I have a trait that takes a callback, the callback should mutate a variable from the scope it was defined in. But I get an error saying the borrowed value does not live long enough.

```
pub struct Target<T> {
    funcs: Vec<Box<dyn FnMut(T) -> ()>>,
}
impl<T: Clone + 'static> Target<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Target<T> {
        return Target { funcs: Vec::new() };
    }
    pub fn add_listener(&mut self, func: Box<dyn FnMut(T) -> ()>) -> () {
        self.funcs.push(Box::new(func));
    }
    pub fn trigger(&mut self, x: T) {

          for callback in &mut self.funcs {
            callback(x.clone());
          }
    }
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn trigger_mutation() {
        let mut a = 0;
        let mut t: Target<i32> = Target::new();
        t.add_listener(Box::new(|x: i32| {
            println!("{}", x);
            a = x;
        }));
        t.trigger(42);
        let b = a.clone();
        assert_eq!(b, 42);

    }
}
```

I run it and get this:

```
$ cargo test -- --nocapture                                                                                                                                                                                            
   Compiling luma-connector v0.1.0 (/home/blake/git/connector)                                                                                                                                                                                 
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  --> src/target.rs:32:13                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
30 |           t.add_listener(Box::new(|x: i32| {                                                                                                                                                                                              
   |                          -        -------- value captured here                                                                                                                                                                            
   |  ________________________|                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   | |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
31 | |             println!("{}", x);                                                                                                                                                                                                          
32 | |             a = x + 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   | |             ^ borrowed value does not live long enough                                                                                                                                                                                  
33 | |         }));                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   | |__________- cast requires that `a` is borrowed for `'static`                                                                                                                                                                             
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
37 |       }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   |       - `a` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I get an error saying the borrowed value does not live long enough.

Well yes, your typing of `Target` implies nothing about scoping, so as far as the Rust typesystem is concerned, the closure could just fly into space unbouded by time (e.g. `add_listener` could pass it to a separate thread), therefore outlive `trigger_mutation`, which means `a` does not live long enough.

There are two ways to resolve this issue:

Use `Arc`/`Rc` with interior mutability (resp. `Mutex` and `RefCell`) in order to relax the lifetime of `a`: [Arc version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9430c40b78cb79fe46402a979e9d6376)[0], [Rc version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1f632ff8979e9efbe0467d7281c744e), this is probably the simplest, and the least restrictive on `Target`, though it comes at a runtime cost.

Alternatively you can "scope" `Target` to tell Rust that it doesn't escape, therefore everything's perfectly kosher. I'm not sure it's the best way (hopefully somebody else can contribute that information) but bounding the `FnMut`s on a lifetime will allow rustc  to reason about this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e67a4ab0faa8cc5d01c75293623c9fb4

This is basically free at runtime, but it means `Target` can't really escape its function.

So the former is probably what you want, the latter seems not super-useful for an events / notification system, but YMMV.

[0] an `Atomic*` would also work for the `Arc` version and be a bit easier & cheaper than a mutex, though it probably isn't very relevant for a test case.